# Getting mixed messages about coroutines

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I've been trying to wrap my head around coroutines and I believe I have a fairly good understanding now, but there's still a couple things that aren't clear which I have questions about.

Imagine I have the below code:

```
lateinit var item: Int

val coroutine = globalScope.launch {
    item = onePlusOne()
}

suspend fun onePlusOne(): Int {
    return 1+1
}
```

1. When the suspend function `onePlusOne` is called, it doesn't start a new coroutine correct? It is still executing in the same one started by launch?
2. When the suspend function `onePlusOne` is called, it doesn't automatically suspend the coroutine that launch created right? If it does, how does it still execute the `return 1+1` statement?

Comment: Hey regarding 1. yes same as any function.
2. no it does not, and in you case it won't suspend at all, a suspend KW says this function CAN be suspended, but it is not mandatory, you are missing a WithContext(Dispachers.XX) statement in the start of the suspended function this statement selects the thread pool used to execute this function. Without it you would execute it on the UI thread and if you would call a blocking method you will block the UI

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. When the suspend function onePlusOne is called, it doesn't start a new coroutine correct? It is still executing in the same one started by launch?

Yes, a coroutine is only created when you create one from [CoroutineScope.launch](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/launch.html) or [CoroutineScope.async](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/async.html), [withContext](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/with-context.html) or [runBlocking](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/run-blocking.html).

A suspend function does not create a new coroutine, but can suspend the caller if it calls any suspend function from inside it (it can be change of thread/dispatcher using [withContext](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/with-context.html) and waiting for the result, it can be a [delay](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/delay.html), or you are using [suspendCancellableCoroutine](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.coroutines/suspend-cancellable-coroutine.html) to wrap a callback and resume/return the value as function return, and many more).

> When the suspend function onePlusOne is called, it doesn't automatically suspend the coroutine that launch created right? If it does, how does it still execute the return 1+1 statement?

Yes it doesn't suspend it, unless you call a suspend function it is not suspended.

Suspend functions aren't magical that they suspend on their own, they are same as a non-suspend function, but they have one extra parameter appended at the time of compilation accepting a [Continuation](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.coroutines/-continuation/), which basically work as a callback to pause (suspend) and resume a coroutine.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. What is still unclear to me is the part "(it can be change of thread/dispatcher using withContext and waiting for the result, it can be a delay, or you are using suspendCancellableCoroutine to wrap a callback and resume/return the value as function return, and many more)." Why would withContext suspend the coroutine? Wouldn't it have to create another one to execute its body?

Comment: @Graham it suspends the calling coroutine starts new one and when it finishes it resumes the calling coroutine. Due to the fact we have to change the context (dispatcher in most case).

Comment: Ah I think I missed the "waiting for result" part. So if you do a withContext and have an async/await in its body it would suspend. The way its explained in so many tutorials "a suspend function suspends the coroutine" is very misleading. It's only specific suspend functions provided by the coroutines library that will actually suspend.